# How to create multiple JmsQueueEndpoint object for different selector using Endpoint class

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue where I want to process Selected messages and am able to achieve it using Java DSL as below:

```
from("amq:queue:{{jms.miscQueue}}?transacted=false&selector=DSBSelectorID %3D '" + SELECTOR_ID_TRANSACTION_A2A + "'")

from("amq:queue:{{jms.miscQueue}}?transacted=false&selector=DSBSelectorID %3D '" + SELECTOR_ID_TRANSACTION_A2P + "'")
```

Now I want to achieve the same by creating JMS Endpoints as below (Actually Java DSL works fine but it gets difficult to debug over time as more and more option is embedded to the URI) :

```
 JmsQueueEndpoint activeMQEndpointA2A = endpoint("amq:queue:{{jms.miscQueue}}", JmsQueueEndpoint.class);
 activeMQEndpointA2A.setTransacted(false);
 activeMQEndpointA2A.setSelector("DSBSelectorID %3D 'Route-Transaction-A2A'");


 JmsQueueEndpoint activeMQEndpointA2P = endpoint("amq:queue:{{jms.miscQueue}}", JmsQueueEndpoint.class);
 activeMQEndpointA2P.setTransacted(false);
 activeMQEndpointA2P.setSelector("DSBSelectorID %3D 'Route-Transaction-A2P'");
```

And when I use activeMQEndpointA2A and activeMQEndpointA2P in my Camel Routes it only works for the first Endpoint and second endpoint is unable to connect to the queue and keeps throwing error as below

> Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination
>   'io.az.jms' - trying to recover. Cause: DSBSelectorID %3D
>   'Route-Transaction-A2P'

Can someone suggest if it's achievable through Java Endpoint or not? Also if I have several routes and there are multiple options to be defined on the Endpoint URI what's the recommended approach?

Comment: Did you add those endpoints to `context`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, get an endpoint and then mutate its properties, and then get the endpoint again (you get the same instance as the first) eg A2A and A2P are the same endpoint instance.

You need to use unique endpoints and hence the selector should be in the uri